# Writing data in an already made file

Tags: java, file, io, file-handling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to append text to an existing file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java)

I ave a file already made in C:\myfile.txt and it has some data in it.. Now when I try to use File files = new File("C:\myfile.txt"); , It overwrites th orignal data and inserts the new data in it.. Is there a mechanism to aviod overwriting of old data?...

Comment: Do you want to add data to the file?  Consider [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java)  Otherwise what would you like to happen to the old and new files?

Comment: Absolutely. How would your code know what to do with the existing data?

Comment: Look at this [FileOutputStream Constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File, boolean)) and it's `boolean append` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use append mode in one of the file writer classes:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("myfile.txt", true);
```

Answer (score 3):

use the method `new FileOutputStream(File,true)` to append to an existing file.

Answer (score 1):

Provide `true` in the constructor to append the file as told above
For more detailed control, use `RandomAccessFile`